# Error downloading any generated Java file

Tags: java, excel, apache, pdf, itext

I have a web application which I have deployed on a local server, I have two classes to generate PDF files and Excel the libraries. I am using are Apache POI and iText PDF 5.4.3. When I run tests on my NetBeans it works perfectly, it generates the files. But when I display the .war on the server by means of Apache and try to generate the files, it tells me that it was generated correctly but I go to the path that the files should be but they are not however the application tells me that they were generated correctly and does not throw any errors. I am using the administrator session and presents the same error.

These are the PDF classes

```
package Controlador;

import com.itextpdf.text.BaseColor;
import com.itextpdf.text.Chunk;
import com.itextpdf.text.Document;
import com.itextpdf.text.DocumentException;
import com.itextpdf.text.Element;
import com.itextpdf.text.Font;
import com.itextpdf.text.Font.FontFamily;
import com.itextpdf.text.FontFactory;
import com.itextpdf.text.Image;
import com.itextpdf.text.PageSize;
import com.itextpdf.text.Paragraph;
import com.itextpdf.text.pdf.PdfPCell;
import com.itextpdf.text.pdf.PdfPTable;
import com.itextpdf.text.pdf.PdfWriter;
import java.io.*;
import java.sql.PreparedStatement;
import java.sql.ResultSet;
import java.sql.SQLException;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;
import modelo.conexion;
import java.util.Calendar;

public class GeneratePDF extends conexion {

    List<Informe> listp;
    String nombreF = "";
    String sed = "";
    List<Informe> listafinal = new ArrayList<Informe>();

    public boolean createPDF(int var, String mes, String ano) {

        try {

            Calendar now = Calendar.getInstance();
            String mess = String.valueOf(now.get(Calendar.MONTH));
            if (mess.length() <= 1) {
                mess = "0" + mess;
            }
            Fechas fechas = new Fechas();
            mess = fechas.Mes(mess);

            String anoo = String.valueOf(now.get(Calendar.YEAR));
            String day = String.valueOf(now.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH));

            //(List<Informe>)lista;
            String sede = sed;
            if (sede.equalsIgnoreCase("0")) {
                sede = "";
            }
            String nombre = nombreF;

            if (var == 0) {
                Document documento = new Document(PageSize.LETTER, 50, 50, 7, 5);
                FileOutputStream ficheroPdf = new FileOutputStream(new File(System.getProperty("user.home") + "/Downloads/Certificaciones/certificiacion" + nombre + ".PDF"));
            }
            Document documento = new Document(PageSize.LETTER, 50, 50, 7, 5);
            FileOutputStream ficheroPdf = new FileOutputStream(new File(System.getProperty("user.home") + "/Downloads/Certificaciones(" + var + ")/Certificiación " + nombre + ".PDF"));

            PdfWriter.getInstance(documento, ficheroPdf).setInitialLeading(5);
            documento.open();
            documento.addTitle("Certificacion");
            documento.addAuthor("Emrs");
            documento.addCreator("Emrs");
            try {
                Image foto = Image.getInstance("web/resource/img/encabezado.PNG");
                foto.scaleToFit(400, 80);
                foto.setAlignment(Chunk.ALIGN_CENTER);

                documento.add(foto);
            } catch (DocumentException | IOException e) {
                System.out.println("Controlador.GeneratePDF.createPDF()" + e);
            }
//Añadir titulo
            Paragraph titulo = new Paragraph("CERTIFICADO DE APROVECHAMIENTO Y DISPOSICIÓN FINAL", FontFactory.getFont("TIMES_ROMAN", // fuente
                    12, // tamaño
                    Font.BOLD, // estilo
                    BaseColor.BLACK));
            titulo.setAlignment(Element.ALIGN_CENTER);
            documento.add(new Paragraph(titulo));
//Añadir cuerpo
            Paragraph cuerpo = new Paragraph("\nLa Asociación Entidad Medioambiental de Recicladores-EMRS ESP-, prestador del servicio público complementario de aprovechamiento, certifica que " + nombre + " " + sede + " en el mes de " + mes + " de " + ano + " realizó entrega de los siguientes residuos y en las cantidades que se relacionan a continuación:\n\n", FontFactory.getFont("TIMES_ROMAN", // fuente
                    12, // tamaño

                    BaseColor.BLACK));
            cuerpo.setAlignment(Element.ALIGN_JUSTIFIED);
            documento.add(new Paragraph(cuerpo));
//Añadir tabla
            PdfPTable tabla = new PdfPTable(4);
            Font font = new Font(FontFamily.TIMES_ROMAN, 10, Font.BOLD);
            Paragraph clase = new Paragraph("CLASE MATERIAL", font);
            clase.setAlignment(Element.ALIGN_CENTER);
            clase.setLeading(0, 1);
            Paragraph tipo = new Paragraph("TIPO MATERIAL", font);
            tipo.setAlignment(Element.ALIGN_CENTER);
            tipo.setLeading(0, 1);
            Paragraph kilos = new Paragraph("TOTAL EN KILOS", font);
            kilos.setAlignment(Element.ALIGN_CENTER);
            kilos.setLeading(0, 1);
            Paragraph por = new Paragraph("PORCENTAJE", font);
            por.setAlignment(Element.ALIGN_CENTER);
            por.setLeading(0, 1);
            PdfPCell clas = new PdfPCell();
            clas.setMinimumHeight(15);
            clas.setVerticalAlignment(Element.ALIGN_CENTER);
            PdfPCell tip = new PdfPCell();
            tip.setMinimumHeight(15);
            tip.setVerticalAlignment(Element.ALIGN_CENTER);
            PdfPCell kilo = new PdfPCell();
            kilo.setMinimumHeight(15);
            kilo.setVerticalAlignment(Element.ALIGN_CENTER);
            PdfPCell po = new PdfPCell();
            po.setMinimumHeight(15);
            po.setVerticalAlignment(Element.ALIGN_CENTER);
            for (int i = 0; i < 4; i++) {
                clas.addElement(clase);
                tabla.addCell(clas);
                i++;
                tip.addElement(tipo);
                tabla.addCell(tip);
                i++;
                kilo.addElement(kilos);
                tabla.addCell(kilo);
                i++;
                po.addElement(por);
                tabla.addCell(po);
            }
            tabla.setWidthPercentage(100);
            documento.add(tabla);
            //   tabla.addCell(String clase = (String)lista.get(1));
            PdfPTable tablaMaterial = new PdfPTable(4);
            double sK = 0.0;
            double porcentaje = 0.0;

            ArrayList porc = new ArrayList();

            for (Informe ki : listafinal) {

                double kil = Double.parseDouble(ki.getTotal());
                sK += kil;
            }

            for (Informe consulta : listafinal) {

                String nit = consulta.getNit();
                String clasem = consulta.getClase();
                String tipom = consulta.getTipo();
                String totalt = consulta.getTotal();
                //  tablaMaterial.addCell(clasem);
                //  tablaMaterial.addCell(tipom);
                //  tablaMaterial.addCell(totalt);

                for (int i = 0; i < 4; i++) {

                    tablaMaterial.addCell(clasem);
                    i++;
                    tablaMaterial.addCell(tipom);
                    i++;
                    Paragraph kil = new Paragraph(totalt + " K");
                    kil.setAlignment(Element.ALIGN_CENTER);
                    kil.setLeading(0, 1);
                    tablaMaterial.addCell(kil);
                    i++;
                    double ki = Double.parseDouble(totalt);
                    porcentaje = ki * 100 / sK;
                    porcentaje = Math.round(porcentaje * 100);
                    porcentaje = porcentaje / 100;

                    String p = String.valueOf(porcentaje);
                    tablaMaterial.addCell(p + " %");
                    i++;
                }

            }
            tablaMaterial.setWidthPercentage(100);
            documento.add(tablaMaterial);

//Añadir final
            Paragraph fin = new Paragraph("\nQue estos fueron recolectados por nuestros asociados recicladores de oficio y transportados a nuestra Estación de Clasificación y Aprovechamiento-ECA-, donde se clasificaron, acopiaron y comercializaron a la industria para su transformación y devolución al ciclo productivo. \n", FontFactory.getFont("TIMES_ROMAN", // fuente
                    12, // tamaño

                    BaseColor.BLACK));
            fin.setAlignment(Element.ALIGN_JUSTIFIED);
            documento.add(new Paragraph(fin));

//Añadir fecha
            Paragraph fec = new Paragraph("\nSe firma a los " + day + " días del mes de " + mess + " de " + anoo + ". ", FontFactory.getFont("TIMES_ROMAN", // fuente
                    12, // tamaño

                    BaseColor.BLACK));
            fec.setAlignment(Element.ALIGN_JUSTIFIED);
            documento.add(new Paragraph(fec));
//Añadir firma
//            Paragraph fir = new Paragraph("\n___________________________\n"
//                    + "VIVIANA ROMERO OCAMPO\n"
//                    + "Subgerencia de Recolección y Transporte\n"
//                    + "ASOCIACIÓN ENTIDAD MEDIOAMBIENTAL DE RECICLADORES-EMRS ESP-", FontFactory.getFont("TIMES_ROMAN", // fuente
//                            12, // tamaño
//
//                            BaseColor.BLACK));
//            fir.setAlignment(Element.ALIGN_CENTER);
//            documento.add(new Paragraph(fir));

            try {
                Image firma = Image.getInstance("web/resource/img/logo.png");
                firma.scaleToFit(400, 400);
                firma.setAlignment(Chunk.ALIGN_CENTER);

                documento.add(firma);
            } catch (DocumentException | IOException e) {
                System.out.println("Controlador.GeneratePDF.createPDF()" + e);
            }

            documento.close();

        } catch (DocumentException | FileNotFoundException e) {
            System.err.println("Controlador.GeneratePDF.createPDF() " + e);
            return false;
        }

        return true;

    }
```

And this is the one of Excel

```
package modelo;

import Controlador.Informe;
import java.awt.Desktop;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileOutputStream;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.sql.PreparedStatement;
import java.sql.ResultSet;
import java.sql.SQLException;
import java.sql.Statement;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;
import org.apache.poi.hssf.usermodel.HSSFWorkbook;
import org.apache.poi.ss.usermodel.Cell;
import org.apache.poi.ss.usermodel.Row;
import org.apache.poi.ss.usermodel.Sheet;
import org.apache.poi.ss.usermodel.Workbook;

/**
 *
 * @author hp
 */
public class Informes extends conexion {

    List<Informe> listaf = new ArrayList<Informe>();

    public boolean aprovecha(String ini, String fin) throws SQLException, IOException {
        Statement st = con.createStatement();
        ResultSet rs = null;
        String nit;
        int numRecibo;
        String inir = ini.replace("-", "");
        String finr = fin.replace("-", "");

        PreparedStatement consulta = con.prepareStatement("select DISTINCT nit_fuente from fuentes where activo = 'SI'");

        try {
            rs = consulta.executeQuery();
            String rutaArchivo = System.getProperty("user.home") + "/Downloads/SuscriptoresAforados.xls";
            File archivoXLS = new File(rutaArchivo);
            int ff = 0;
            int var = 0;
            while (ff == 0) {
                if (archivoXLS.exists()) {
                    var++;
                    rutaArchivo = System.getProperty("user.home") + "/Downloads/SuscriptoresAforados(" + var + ").xls";
                    archivoXLS = new File(rutaArchivo);
                } else {
                    ff = 1;
                }
            }

            archivoXLS.createNewFile();
            Workbook libro = new HSSFWorkbook();
            FileOutputStream archivo = new FileOutputStream(archivoXLS);
            Sheet hoja = libro.createSheet("Hoja 1");
            int f = 0;
            while (rs.next()) {
                nit = rs.getString("nit_fuente");
                ResultSet rsmate = null;
//                PreparedStatement consultarecibo = con.prepareStatement("select clasematerial,tipoMaterial,nit_asociado,sum(cantidad) as Total "
//                        + "from ingresomaterial "
//                        + "LEFT JOIN recibo on ingresomaterial.numRecibo = recibo.num_recibo "
//                        + "WHERE nit_fuente = " + nit + " and num_recibo BETWEEN '170000' and '170176' "
//                        + "GROUP BY tipoMaterial");
                PreparedStatement consultarecibo = con.prepareStatement("select clasematerial,tipoMaterial,sede,nit_asociado,sum(cantidad) as total "
                        + "from ingresomaterial "
                        + "LEFT JOIN recibo on ingresomaterial.numRecibo = recibo.num_recibo "
                        + "WHERE nit_fuente ='" + nit + "' and FECHa BETWEEN '" + inir + "' and '" + finr + "' "
                        + "GROUP BY tipoMaterial ");
                rsmate = consultarecibo.executeQuery();
                System.out.println("modelo.Informes.aprovecha()" + consultarecibo);
                while (rsmate.next()) {

                    Informe lista = new Informe(nit, rsmate.getString("clasematerial"), rsmate.getString("tipoMaterial"),
                            rsmate.getString("total"), rsmate.getString("nit_asociado"), rsmate.getString("sede"));

                    listaf.add(lista);
                }

            }

            consruta(inir, finr);

            for (int x = 0; x < listaf.size(); x++) {
                //  System.out.println(listaf.get(x));
                Row fila = hoja.createRow(x);
                for (int c = 0; c < 5;) {
                    /*Creamos la celda a partir de la fila actual*/
                    Cell celda = fila.createCell(c);

                    if (x == 0) {
                        switch (c) {
                            case 0:
                                celda.setCellValue("Nit Fuente");
                                break;
                            case 1:
                                celda.setCellValue("Nit Asosicado");
                                break;
                            case 2:
                                celda.setCellValue("Clase");
                                break;
                            case 3:
                                celda.setCellValue("Total");
                                break;
                            case 4:
                                celda.setCellValue("Total Toneladas ");

                                break;
                        }
                    } else {
                        /*Si no es la primera fila establecemos un valor*/

                        switch (c) {
                            case 0:
                                celda.setCellValue(listaf.get(x).getNit());
                                break;
                            case 1:
                                celda.setCellValue(listaf.get(x).getNitSocio());
                                break;
                            case 2:
                                celda.setCellValue(listaf.get(x).getClase());
                                break;
                            case 3:
                                celda.setCellValue(listaf.get(x).getTipo());
                                break;
                            case 4:
                                double total = Double.parseDouble(listaf.get(x).getTotal());

                                celda.setCellValue(total);

                                break;
                        }

                    }
                    c++;
                }

            }

            libro.write(archivo);
            archivo.close();
            Desktop.getDesktop().open(archivoXLS);
        } catch (Exception e) {

            System.err.print("error " + e);

            return false;
        }
        con.close();

        return true;
    }
```

The server is windows, or I have provided absolute paths because it may be disk c or d.

Comment: Could you add some actual logging rather than `System.err.println` and see the logs? Are there any errors? What are they? Also, have you tried to debug it?

Comment: When debug in netbens works bn but on server does not throw error indicates that it was generated correctly

Comment: You use `System.getProperty("user.home")` in your target file path - have you checked which user your servlet server runs as? Simply log the target file name to make sure...